# Let $P_N(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^N\frac{z^n}{n!}$. Calculate $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\int_{|z|=2}\frac{1}{P^3(z) - 1}dz$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $P_N(z) = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^N\frac{z^n}{n!}$.  Calculate $\displaystyle\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\int_{|z|=2}\frac{1}{P^3(z) - 1}dz$.

I am not sure how to do this.  If I could figure how to pull the limit in it is easy.  Also, if I could show $P^3(z) - 1$ has only one root once $N$ is so big, then it is easy.  Any suggestions?  Thanks

Also, clearly $P_N(z)$ tends toward $e^z$

Comment: A thought is to write $e^z=P_N(z)+R_{N+1}(z)$, noting that this remainder term is analytic and of leading order $z^{N+1}$.

Comment: Note that, if you have a solution, I'd encourage you to post it below. That way you can accept it yourself if it proves to be the best one (plus we can give feedback about any possible errors.)

Answer (score 2):

$P_N(z)$ converges uniformly towards $e^z$ over any compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$, and the Residue Theorem grants that:
$$\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{dz}{P_N^3(z)-1}=2\pi i\cdot\sum_{\xi\in Z} \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1}{P_N^3(z)-1},z=\xi\right),$$
where $Z$ is the set of zeroes of $P_N^3(z)-1$ that lie inside the disk $|z|\leq 2$. Since the zeroes of $e^{3z}-1$ are located in $\frac{2\pi i}{3}\mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi>3$, the uniform convergence of $P_N^3(z)-1$ towards $e^{3z}-1$ ensures that for $N$ big enough the set $Z$ is made of the origin only, hence:
$$ \oint_{|z|=2}\frac{dz}{P_N^3(z)-1}=\frac{2\pi i}{3 P_N'(0) P_N^2(0)}=\frac{2\pi i}{3}. $$